# SQL grammar for SELECT MIN(DATE)

Tags: sql

I have a table with structure:
`id(INT PK), title(VARCHAR), date(DATE)`

How do I select all distinct titles with their earliest date?

Apparently, `SELECT DISTINCT title, MIN(date) FROM table` doesn't work.

Comment: Don't call a column `date` if you can avoid it. It's only going to cause you problems in the long run.

Comment: To further suggest what @Ben says I would even go with: Don't use as names for tables, variables, columns, stored procedures, functions etc.,  any SQL reserved words.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` if you want to use aggregation functions.

```
SELECT title, MIN(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY title
```

Answer (score 7):

An aggregate function requires a GROUP BY in standard SQL

This is "Get minimum date per title" in plain language

```
SELECT title, MIN(date) FROM table GROUP BY title
```

Most RDBMS and the standard require that column is either in the GROUP BY or in a functions (MIN, COUNT etc): MySQL is the notable exception with some extensions that give unpredictable behaviour

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` here.

```
SELECT title, MIN (date) FROM table GROUP BY title
```

Above should fix this. And you don't even need a `DISTINCT` now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get updated records then you can use the following query.

```
SELECT title, MAX(date) FROM table GROUP BY title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MIN(Date)  AS Date  FROM tbl_Employee /*To get First date Of Employee*/
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the titles for dates greater than a week ago today, use this:

`SELECT title, MIN(date_key_no) AS intro_date FROM table HAVING MIN(date_key_no)>= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'YYYYMMDD')) - 7`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(t.date)
FROM table t
```